# Add class to every x elements

Tags: css

I have an undefined number of divs for displaying products in a product list page, each row has 4 divs, one for each product.
What I need is to assign a CSS class to the 1st div of each row, then another CSS class to the 2nd div of each row etc.
I'm sure you can do this with CSS and maybe jQuery but I haven't a clue what to search for.

The desired output would look like this:

```
<div> //row1
  <div id="1" class="grid1"> Product 1 </div>
  <div id="2" class="grid2"> Product 2 </div>
  <div id="3" class="grid3"> Product 3 </div>
  <div id="4" class="grid4"> Product 4 </div>
</div>
<div> //row 2
  <div id="5" class="grid1"> Product 5 </div>
  <div id="6" class="grid2"> Product 6 </div>
  <div id="7" class="grid3"> Product 7 </div>
  <div id="8" class="grid4"> Product 8 </div>
<div>
...
```

Any points to the right direction would be very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with plain CSS (you don't even need classes for it):

```
div > div:nth-child(1) { ... }
div > div:nth-child(2) { ... }
div > div:nth-child(3) { ... }
div > div:nth-child(4) { ... }
```

A jQuery-based solution could look like this; note that it assumes your row-level divs to have `class="row"`:

```
$('div.row > div').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('grid' + ($(this).index() + 1));
});
```

Comment: +1 for the solution as semantic as ever possible. ) Will need a shim for IE8, though.

Comment: @SimonArnold: He did not mention that he needs to support legacy browsers.